# C# - How to find all items in SortedDictionary which have similar keys?

Tags: c#, key, sorteddictionary

I have a SortedDictionary:

```
static SortedDictionary<string, int> myDictionary = new SortedDictionary<string, int>();
```

where the keys represent strings something like that:

```
string key = someNumber + " " + row + " " + col + " " + someString;
```

What I want is to find all the items in the sorted dictionary that have specific row and col. For example if I have the following keys:

```
1 2 3 p 
3 2 3 p 
2 2 3 t 
5 1 6 p 
8 2 1 p 
7 2 3 t
```

I want to get only these keys that have row=2 and col=3:

```
1 2 3 p 
3 2 3 p 
2 2 3 t 
7 2 3 t
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately in this case you need to iterate over the whole collection and select the items that match your criteria (so not much use of the dictionary itself):

```
public IList<int> FindValues(int row, int col)
{
    myDictionary
        .Where(item => MatchKey(item.Key, row, col))
        .Select(item => item.Value)
        .ToList();
}

public bool MatchKey(string key, int row, int col)
{
    var splitKey = key.Split();
    return splitKey[1] == row.ToString() && splitKey[2] == col.ToString();
    // or match the key according to your logic
}
```

Though if you need to query by row and column often, then it's better to build a different data structure first. Maybe

```
Dictionary<Coord, IList<int>> myDict;
```

Where Coord is a class/struct (and overrides Equals, GetHashCode)

```
class Coord
{
    public int Row { get; set; }
    public int Column { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: +1, I agree with creating a separate class/structure to "group" the objects by row and column. I would just add two things to AlexD's answer:
1) Use `Lookup<Coord, int>` instead of `DIctionary<Coords, IList<int>>`. It's effectively the same, but I find it much easier to work with.
2) Don't forget to add `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods to the `Coords` class, otherwise the Dictionary/Lookup would compare only the references, which is undesirable in this case.